# how to combine same elements and sum their values in lists in C#

Tags: c#, list

I've two lists that are same size. First list has some titles and the second list has also values of first list's elements. For example;

```
var first = {"1", "saka", "2", "1", "1", "3", "saka", "1", "stack", "3"};
var second = {20,     23,  25,  30,  20,  15,     16,  61,      34,  35};
```

I want 2 new lists that contains combined same elements of mentioned as above and their sums.

```
var F = {"1", "saka", "2", "3", "stack"}
var S = {131,     39,  25,  50,      34}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problems have you had with those attempts?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: do you know the name of all the titles?

Comment: No, I don't know any titles. They will be seen in runtime.

Comment: @RustyH, there is nothing wrong with homework question, as long as effort is put into the question.

Comment: @gunr2171 Not saying there is but they didn't even try just asked "how can i do this"

Comment: @RustyH, I agree that this question is bad (I voted to close). I just want to say that "being a homework question" shouldn't be a determining factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void hereIsYourAnswer()
    {
        string [] first = { "1", "saka", "2", "1", "1", "3", "saka", "1", "stack", "3" };
        int [] second = { 20, 23, 25, 30, 20, 15, 16, 61, 34, 35 };

        List<String> F = new List<string>();
        List<int> S = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
        {
            if (F.Contains(first[i]))
                S[F.IndexOf(first[i])] += second[i];
            else
            {
                F.Add(first[i]);
                S.Add(second[i]);
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < S.Count; i++)
            MessageBox.Show(F[i] + " = " + S[i].ToString());

                //Output
                //1=131
                //saka=39
                //2=25
                //3=50
                //stack=34


    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However I need titles, too.

Comment: thats what your stringList is. Index of stringList correlates to index of sum in addedList

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't see stringList. Thanks for your answer. Can be more speedy a linq  solution?

Comment: Not familiar with linq so I wouldn't know. This is what you were looking for though right?

Comment: A LINQ solution would involve zipping the two lists, grouping the resultant tuples by values from the "first" list, averaging each group, and projecting each grouped average into a tuple with group name and averaged value.